# Channel unregistered before processing completed

Tags: java, netty, apache-nifi, netty-socketio

I have a very unclear and difficult to understand problem. In the NiFi flow, certain processors use services:

- `DistributedMapCacheClientService` (v. 1.20.0)
- `DistributedMapCacheServer` (v. 1.20.0)

and `DistributedMapCacheClientService` connects to `DistributedMapCacheServer`.

For some reason, we sometimes get:

```
java.io.IOException: Request invocation failed
    at org.apache.nifi.distributed.cache.client.CacheClientRequestHandler.invoke(CacheClientRequestHandler.java:103)
    at org.apache.nifi.distributed.cache.client.MyDistributedCacheClient.invoke(DistributedCacheClient.java:69)
    at org.apache.nifi.distributed.cache.client.NettyDistributedMapCacheClient.getAndPutIfAbsent(NettyDistributedMapCacheClient.java:140)
    at org.apache.nifi.distributed.cache.client.DistributedMapCacheClientService.getAndPutIfAbsent(DistributedMapCacheClientService.java:154)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor471.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.service.StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.java:254)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.service.StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.java:105)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy175.getAndPutIfAbsent(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.DetectDuplicate.onTrigger(DetectDuplicate.java:184)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1357)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:246)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:102)
    at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Channel unregistered before processing completed: [id: 0x7288e0ed, L:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:38868]
    at org.apache.nifi.distributed.cache.client.CacheClientRequestHandler.channelUnregistered(CacheClientRequestHandler.java:70)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:219)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:195)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:188)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelUnregistered(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1388)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:215)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:195)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelUnregistered(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:821)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$7.run(AbstractChannel.java:821)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:569)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    ... 1 more
```

This is the configuration of `DistributedMapCacheClientService`:
[image]
Host name and port are all well configured.

I have examined all the log files, but I'm unable to find the root cause of this problem.

We have been debugging the project by connecting from the NiFi source to the remote JVM (i.e. NiFi running instance). We've managed to find out, that `handShakeHandler`, from the source below (`CacheClientRequestHandler`), occasionally happens to be `null`.

[image]

Why `handShakeHandler` can be `null` and in what circumstances?

Comment: What's your queue limit and is it filled up when you start seeing the error?  Can you adjust the timeout for that process and see if you get fewer (or none) errors? I mean it almost feels like some sort of race condition, but that shouldn't really happen..

Comment: What do you mean in queue limit? I don't have such. It feels like so, yes.. but timeout is 5 seconds as you can see in the screenshot, which must be quite enough for such a race.

Comment: I might be thinking of a global setting, can't remember exactly. But I'm pretty sure there was a limit on how many flows can sit in a queue. But the default is quite high so I was only curious.

Comment: Even if we've cleared that queue (just stopped processor and redirected the connection/relation somewhere else), this still (not piling up, but the `Channel unregistered...` exception) happens every since in a while.

Comment: @Phaelaxz it's 10 000.. so, it's not a problem.

Comment: And what's the closing vote reason?

Comment: Not sure who voted to close it, not me. But I'm afraid I can't help any further in your case. There's still many aspects of nifi I'm still learning myself.

Comment: @Phaelaxz thanks, I didn't even suspect it was you.. otherwise, why would you have got involved into discussion at all.